# Apache camel 3.18.3 http component HTTP_PATH header not working with toD

Tags: java, apache-camel

I tried to make work the example in camel toD eip documentation page

```
from("direct:login")
  .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, simple("/login"))
  .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("userid=${header.userName}"))
  .toD("http:myloginserver:8080")
  .removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH)
  .removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY);
```

but the header `Exchange.HTTP_PATH` is not used, so as result the following url is called: `http://myloginserver:8080?userid=xxx` and not `http://myloginserver:8080/login?userid=xxx`.
I debugged the code I found that the issue could be in the class `org.apache.camel.http.base.HttpSendDynamicAware` in the method `createPreProcessor` at line 96.
In this method the url in toD is parsed and the path is an empty string "", and it's not checked if the `Exchange.HTTP_PATH` is set.
I'm upgrading from camel 3.11.x and it used to work, but in that version there isn't the class `HttpSendDynamicAware`.

Is there a way to make it work without changing the code?

Thanks

Comment: why dont you use to.( instead of toD ? toD means if I am not wrong dynamically change on runtime.

Comment: What I reported it's an example from official Camel documentation, but my code has a dynamic path expression.

Answer (score 0):

I created an issue in Apache Camel JIRA
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-18782

Thanks to Claus Ibsen

it's a bug, it will be fixed in next releases.

It can be workaround as follows:

```
from("direct:login")
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, simple("/login"))
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("userid=${header.userName}"))
.toD().allowOptimisedComponents(false).uri("http:myloginserver:8080")
.removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH)
.removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY);
```